# Repeating controlChanges on GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, controller, event-listener

I'm working on learning about using events to change things on the GUI. I am currently using Controller Events passed from another method and I think I may be missing some key information about how variables work in these methods. Here is my source code (this is currently an inner class).

```
class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel implements ControllerEventListener{

    static boolean isWriting = false;

    public void controlChange(ShortMessage event) {
        isWriting = true;
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        if (isWriting){
            int red = (int) (Math.random() * 250);
            int green = (int) (Math.random() * 250);
            int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 250);

            g.setColor(new Color(red, green, blue));

            int xpos = (int) (Math.random() * 190 + 10);
            int ypos = (int) (Math.random() * 190 + 10);
            int width = (int) (Math.random() * 50 + 10);
            int height = (int) (Math.random() * 50 + 10);
            g.fillRect(xpos, ypos, width, height);


            //isWriting = false;
        }
```

What I'm trying to do is draw a new rectangle every time the listener receives an event but I can only get one of two things to happen. If I try to set "isWriting" back to false at the end of the if statement the if statement seems to continuously evaluate to false and not draw any rectangles. If I comment out that code to set isWriting back to false the drawing works for a single rectangle but there is nothing to change the variable back and call the repaint method so I only get a single rectangle.

I know that my events are getting to the listener as I've used a sout to increment a count every time it gets an event so it seems the problem is with the state of the isWriting variable. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Never change the state of your class from within a painting method. I'm not clear and what exactly you're trying to do here, what behavior you're trying to elicit. Can you clarify?

Comment: Do you want the rectangle to display only for a period of time? If so, use a Swing Timer. Or when user acknowledges receipt of the message? Then use an other listener. Again, please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You want to avoid changing the state of your class from within a painting method. This is not a method that you have full control over, and so doing this can lead to unexpected and difficult to debug side effects.

I'm not 100% certain of what you're trying to do, but if you're trying to draw a new rectangle each time a message is received, and you want that rectangle to persist (and in this way, perhaps show multiple rectangles), then,

- Either draw the rectangles onto a BufferedImage, and then display the BufferedImage into your JPanel's paintComponent method, or
- Create an ArrayList of an object that contains both a Rectangle and a Color, and then with each event, create a new one of these objects, add it to the list, and call `repaint()`. Then within paintComponent, iterate through the list drawing the rectangles.
- Don't forget that you should always call the super's paintComponent method within your override.

Otherwise if you want the rectangle to display only for a period of time then use a Swing Timer. Or if when user acknowledges receipt of the message, then use an other listener. Again, please clarify your question.

Tutorials:

- [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html): introductory tutorial to Swing graphics
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html): advanced tutorial on Swing graphics

Comment: You hit the nail on the head with what I'm trying to do with leaving each rectangle. I'm still a super beginner when it comes to all things java (and honestly pretty new to programming in general) so it's going to take me some time to try to put together something with your suggestions (I've been looking into it for an hour or so now and haven't made a lot of progress, bufferedimages are totally new to me and arraylists are still something I'm learning) so I won't be able to tell you if it worked for a few days.

Comment: One question I have is in your 3rd bullet what overridden method should I be calling the repaint method from? I'm not actually sure what method I'm overriding.

Comment: @bailey2092: You would call the super's method in the override -- you're overriding paintComponent. Please see the first tutorial that I've just now posted a link to in the answer above. The second tutorial goes into greater detail if you're interested.

Comment: Yeah I've been working on this for two weeks and haven't gotten anywhere. My code is a mess now because I have no idea where anything in swing should go and no idea where the listeners should go.   I can't figure out how to add the rectangle object to an arraylist and include the color and the dimensions. I can't figure out what the Event Dispatch Thread is or what runnable is even supposed to do because it's greyed out in my code like it's unused. I don't know when to repaint or how to call repaint from another method.

Comment: @bailey2092: fix one problem at a time, and often do so in isolation from the rest of your program, in small test programs, including a small program to work out your listener problem, a small one to work out your painting problem, etc.

Comment: Thanks for trying man. There are like no decent resources to learn java as a beginner. It seems like none of the syntax is even logical at all. I've read a 600 page java book and countless javadocs and now I just feel like the last 7 weeks have been wasted. I think I have to be done. Apps are just so out of the league of anyone who doesn't have anyone to actually help them learn and I can't afford school and the nearest usergroup meetup is 2 hours away (good ol' 700 person town and crippling social anxiety anyway). /sad rant

Comment: I tried that. I have several programs that can paint and several programs that can listen and several midi programs. It's just when I try to tie them together the classes don't even seem to talk to each other. It's just been so much time of thinking "Hey maybe I understand this" then just being smacked in the face realizing I don't at all And no matter what I read or where I go nothing seems to get any clearer. I just am too broken to keep going. I think this is the end of java for me.

Comment: I really appreciate you trying to help. Your answers really seemed like they should have helped me. And sorry for venting at you. It's just been a huge buildup since you first answered. I've been spending 15-60 minutes on it a day and it finally got to me. You deserve the upvote I gave you